# Multiple counts from Powershell Get-ChildItem?

Tags: powershell

How would I use powershell to count the number of files and the number of folders under a folder, emulating the Windows "properties" of that folder?

The [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65931/cross-posting-on-stackexchange-sites) says cross-posting is OK, so the full question can be found at: https://superuser.com/questions/605911/multiple-counts-from-powershell-get-childitem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to enumerate all files and folders for a given path and maintain a count of each object type:

```
$files=$folders=0
$path = "d:\temp"

dir $path -recurse | foreach { if($_.psiscontainer) {$folders+=1} else {$files+=1} }

"'$path' contains $files files, $folders folders"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Edited to improve efficiency and stop loops...

This can also be done by using the `Measure-Object` cmdlet with `Get-childItem` cmdlet:

```
gci "C:\" -rec | Measure -property psiscontainer -max -sum | Select `
    @{Name="Path"; Expression={$directory.FullName}},
    @{Name="Files"; Expression={$_.Count - $_.Sum}},
    @{Name="Folders"; Expression={$_.Sum}}
```

**Output:**

```
Path                 Files           Folders
----                 -----           -------
C:\Test              470             19
```

Comment: This will take twice as long as the previous answer, as you're calling `gci` twice and looping through the collection it returns twice. If there are ongoing changes to the directory structure, you may get different output of `gci` between the two invocations.

Comment: @alroc Edited answer is now more efficient and avoids loops.